# Laravel. Разница между фасадами и статическими методами

Tags: php, laravel

Не могу окончательно понять когда лучше и практичнее использовать фасад или статический метод... Все статьи говорят только о границах класса (и их росте, а также в дальнейшем возникновении проблем с внедрением зависимостей).
Так вот, есть ли ещё разница?

P.s. Можно рассмотреть на примере обработки запроса **Request (фасад) vs Http\Request (статический метод)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам непонятно зачем нужны фасады?

Не сильно профессионал в ларавеле, но ляпнуть свое мнение стоит:

Если вас интересует именно чем отличается вызов фасада и напрямую статического класса: то ничем не отличается, кроме того что фасад вам гарантирует более красивое имя вызова.

Фасад по факту и является прямым вызовом статического класса просто с красивым названием. Если нас интересуют другие случаи то там фасад, в каких-то моментах вносит свои преимущества, ну банальный пример: мы можем менять исходные классы, а фасад будет под одним названием. Вы можете справедливо отметить, что такой функционал можно сделать и другими методами, и будете правы, но в этом и фишка ларавел, в нём напиханы все "*лучшие*" практики программирования, и каждый пляшет с чем ему удобнее.